# I'm trying to access a Private Variable from a sub class

Tags: java, object, queue, private

Here is the beginning of my code from my sub class RECORD.

class Record {

```
private int shares;
private int pricePerShare;

// constructor
Record(int sharesNewValue, int pricePerShareNewValue) {
    shares = sharesNewValue;
    pricePerShare = pricePerShareNewValue;
}

// inspectors
public int getShares() {
    return shares;
}

public int getPricePerShare() {
    return pricePerShare;
}

// modifiers
public void setShares(int sharesNewValue) {
    shares = sharesNewValue;
}

public void setPricePerShare(int pricePerShareNewValue) {
    pricePerShare = pricePerShareNewValue;
}
}
```

And I want to access the value of shares in my main method that is in a different class.I have the RECORD class linked to another subclass named QUEUE. And in my main method, I have a link to QUEUE with this:

```
 class Lab04a {
                 public static Queue Q = new Queue(); 
              }
```

Later on in the code, I need to subtract an int value from the SHARES variable in the Record class, but because that is of type Record, I have no clue how to do this!

I'm not sure if I was clear enough when explaining this, should you have any further questions I'll be more than happy to reply.

Thank you.

Due to my inability to coherently state what I'm trying to accomplish in this lab assignment, I'll just post my other two classes in their entirety:

```
 class Queue {

private int count; // number of elements in the queue
private int head; // index of head element, -1 if queue is empty
private int tail; // index of tail element, -1 if queue is empty
private int MAXSIZE = 1; // Physical size of the queue. DO NOT CHANGE!
private Record[] array; // circular array to store the elements of the queue

// constructor
Queue() {
    count = 0;
    head = -1;
    tail = -1;
    array = new Record[MAXSIZE];
}

// inspectors
public boolean empty() {
    // Returns true if the queue is empty. Otherwise returns false.
    return (count != 0);
}

public int size() {
    // Returns the number of elements in the queue
    return count;
}

public Record front(){
    // Returns the head element of the queue if the queue is not empty.
    // Otherwise returns a Record with its data parts set to -1.
    if (count == 0)
        return new Record(-1, -1);
    else
        return array[head];
}

public Record rear(){
    // Returns the tail element of the queue if the queue is not empty.
    // Otherwise returns a Record with its data parts set to -1.
    if (count ==0)
        return new Record(-1, -1);
    else
        return array[tail];

}

public String toString() {
    // Returns the elements of the queue
    String str = "< ";
    int h = head;
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++){
        str += "(" + array[h].getShares() + ", " + array[h].getPricePerShare() + ") ";
        h = (h+1) % MAXSIZE;
    }
    str += ">";
    return str;
}

// modifiers
public boolean dequeue() {
    // Removes the head element of the queue. 
    if (count == 0)
        return false;
    if (count == 1) {
        count = 0;
        head = -1;
        tail = -1;
    } 
    if (count > 1){
        head = (head + 1) % MAXSIZE;
        count--;
    }
    return true;
}

public void enqueue(Record element) {
    // Enqueues element to the tail of the queue.
    //if max size is reached, it doubles the size to allow for more values
    if (count == MAXSIZE) {
        Record[] array2 = new Record[MAXSIZE * 2];
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            array2[i] = array[i];
        }//closes for loop
        array = array2;
        MAXSIZE *= 2;
    }
    tail = (tail + 1) % MAXSIZE;
    array[tail] = element;
    if (count == 0)
        head = tail;
    count++;
}//close enqueue method
```

}//closes class

And then here is my MAIN parent class:

```
 class Lab04a {
public static Queue Q = new Queue(); // creates global object
public static Record R = Record;

public static void main(String args[]) {

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    int option, buyPrice, buyShares, sellPrice, sellShares, totalShares, totalValues, totalSellPrice;
    option = 0;
    totalShares = 0;
    totalValues = 0;
    Queue Q2 = Q;

    while (option != 3) {
        System.out.print("Enter option (1:buy, 2:sell, 3:quit): ");
        option = scan.nextInt();
        if (option == 1) {
            System.out.print("Enter shares to buy and price per share: ");
            buyShares = scan.nextInt();
            buyPrice = scan.nextInt();
            Record r = new Record(buyShares, buyPrice);
            Q.enqueue(r);
            totalShares = totalShares + buyShares;
            totalValues = totalValues + (buyShares * buyPrice);

        }// ends if



        if (option == 2) {
            System.out.print("Enter shares to sell and price per share: ");
            sellShares = scan.nextInt();
            sellPrice = scan.nextInt();
            totalSellPrice = sellPrice * sellShares;

            if (sellShares > totalShares) {
                System.out.println("You do not own enough shares for this sale.");
            }
            for (int i = sellShares; i > 0; ) {
                if (sellShares == Q.front().getShares()) {
                    i -= Q.front().getShares();
                    Q.dequeue();
                }
                if (sellShares < Q.front().getShares()){

                    Record minus; 
                    minus = Q.front() - sellShares;

                    Q.front().setShares(minus);

                    Q.front().setShares(Q.front().getShares());
                    i -= sellShares;
                }
            }


        }// ends if


        // Prints content of Queue
        System.out.println("Queue: " + Q.toString());

        System.out.println("Total Shares: " + totalShares);
        System.out.println("Total Shares Value: $" + totalValues);
        System.out.println();

    }// ends while loop
    System.out.println(Q.toString());
}// ends main method
```

}

Comment: You can't access a private variable from another class, even if it extends the original class. If you want to access the variable add an accessor method.

Comment: Check out "getter" and "setter" methods.

Comment: I do have getters and setters. Its still not working. 
I attempted to use this code: 

Record minus; 
minus = Q.front() - sellShares;

but sellShares is of type int....

Comment: and later on I try to set it to this:    Q.front().setShares(minus);

Comment: Hey guys, I edited the OP to show my complete Record Class

Comment: i am not sure if i am getting it right. you know that you need to instantiate a class before you can access its data?

Comment: How would I instantiate it in the main class?

Comment: If there is still confusion, post your entire code including code for Queue and where you try and access the shares.

Comment: Record record = new Record(20,10); you have to set the initial values for your record. then you can access the getter/setter methods , like record.getShares();

Comment: Hi Dylan, I posted my entire code. Sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question, you can add accessor and [mutator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutator_method) methods (or getters and setters)

```
private int shares;
private int pricePerShare;
public int getShares() {
  return shares;
}
public void setShares(int shares) {
  this.shares = shares;
}
public int getPricePerShare() {
  return pricePerShare;
}
public void setPricePerShare(int pricePerShare) {
  this.pricePerShare = pricePerShare;
}
```

**Edit**

To use it,

```
 Record record = Q.front(); // <-- I assume your Q contains Record(s).
 if (record.getShares() >= sellShares) {
   record.setShares(record.getShares() - sellShares); // <-- for example
 }
```

Comment: I went ahead and added the entire class I have for Record. The other class that I have is a Queue class which contains essential functions for Queue (dequeue, enqueue, size, etc.)

Comment: +1 for accessor and mutator methods.
Oh!!! I got new names for getters and setters!!!!

Comment: @OmarKhalik Edited based on your comments above.

Comment: @AnkitLamba OP added *inspectors* and *modifiers* to his post. I've never heard them used before, but they work too.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure Q.front() is a method that returns a Record.

If that is true, you should be able to use the line

```
Q.front().setShares(Q.front().getShares()-MINUS_VALUE))
```

Comment: Q.front() returns the front element in the queue and thats it. Its an int value. We need to pass multiple values to a queue. Depending on the what the user enters, we either need to delete the first element in the queue, mutate the first element to something different (more specifically the subtraction of first element in queue to the value that user entered)